Shahada for marriage
I am married to a revert. During nikah he said shahada but he had no knowledge of Islam so he didn't mean it, but he knew there is one God later on he didn't practice Islam and but after sometimes he started praying and becomes a good Muslim. Now we are pregnant..I in doubt is our nikah valid or not?

This is a question for Shaykh ( scholar), reach out to your local scholar or imam of your mosque and he will be able to help you inshallah
